# определить что пользователь цикл for

Tags: python

нужно написать такое условия чтобы пользователь вводил цикл for с аргументом и после этого программа делала цикл for c этим аргументом

```
v = input() # for i in range(N)
if True: # условия
    for i in range(N):
        print("1245")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вы можете изменить вопрос с помощью кнопки [edit]

Comment: Нужно сделать чтобы пользователь вводил цикл for с каким-то аргументом и выполнял цикл с этим аргументом

Comment: Обязательно цикл? Или можно просто число нужных повторений?

Comment: @кирилл Как заказывали Хехе:  `exec("for i in range(int(input('Введите количество итераций: '))): print(i)") `

Comment: Приведите пример: **что конкретно вводит пользователь** и **что при таком вводе должен делать код**.

Answer (score 1):

К примеру можно через `regex`

```
import re
v = input() # for i in range(N)

N = re.search(r"for [a-z]+ in range\((\d+)\)", v)

if True: # условия
    for i in range(int(N[1])):
        print("1245")
```

Comment: Сложновато для нового участника. Он наверное даже слов таких не знает